Pandas Dataframe - Group, Rank, and Flatten without Aggregation
I have a dataframe for athletes that includes their athlete ID, team ID, name, and score in a certain competition. Each team can have up to 20 athletes:
Current:
AthleteID    TeamID     Name     Score
   1            2        Bob      4.9
   2            1        Pete     4.6
   3            2        Steve    4.5
   4            1        Jim      3.6
   5            3        Frank    4.2

I would like to have one line per team, sort the athletes by score, and have their information as a column with a rank, as follows:
Desired:
     TeamID     AthleteID_1    Name_1   Score_1     AthleteID_2    Name_2   Score_2
       1              2         Pete      4.6          4            Jim      3.6
       2              1         Bob       4.9          3            Steve    4.5  
       3              5         Frank     4.2        None           None     None    

After grouping by TeamID, how can I sort by score and create those new columns? I am currently doing this iteratively and I know it is not the most efficient or pythonic way.

out = (
    df.assign(
        rank=df.groupby('TeamID')['Score']
        .rank(ascending=False, method='first')
        .astype('int')
        .astype('str')
    )
    .pivot(index='TeamID', columns='rank')
    .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.map('_'.join), axis=1))
    .sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.str.split('_').str[1].astype('int'))
    .reset_index()
)

out:
   TeamID  AthleteID_1 Name_1  Score_1  AthleteID_2 Name_2  Score_2
0       1          2.0   Pete      4.6          4.0    Jim      3.6
1       2          1.0    Bob      4.9          3.0  Steve      4.5
2       3          5.0  Frank      4.2          NaN    NaN      NaN


Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'AthleteID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 
        'TeamID': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 3}, 
        'Name': {0: 'Bob', 1: 'Pete', 2: 'Steve', 3: 'Jim', 4: 'Frank'}, 
        'Score': {0: 4.9, 1: 4.6, 2: 4.5, 3: 3.6, 4: 4.2}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


import pandas as pd

data = {'AthleteID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'TeamID': [2, 1, 2, 1, 3],
        'Name': ['Bob', 'Pete', 'Steve', 'Jim', 'Frank'],
        'Score': [4.9, 4.6, 4.5, 3.6, 4.2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
"""
   AthleteID  TeamID   Name  Score
0          1       2    Bob    4.9
1          2       1   Pete    4.6
2          3       2  Steve    4.5
3          4       1    Jim    3.6
4          5       3  Frank    4.2
"""
res = (
df.sort_values(['TeamID','Score'],ascending=[True,False])
.assign(Rank = lambda d : d.groupby('TeamID').cumcount() +1 )    
.set_index(['TeamID','Rank']).unstack()
.sort_index(axis=1,level =1) # to maintain order
.reset_index()
)
print(res)
"""
     TeamID AthleteID   Name Score AthleteID   Name Score
Rank                1      1     1         2      2     2
0         1       2.0   Pete   4.6       4.0    Jim   3.6
1         2       1.0    Bob   4.9       3.0  Steve   4.5
2         3       5.0  Frank   4.2       NaN    NaN   NaN
"""
#res.columns = [f'{col[0]}_{col[1]}' if col[0] != 'TeamID' else col[0] for col in res.columns]
res.columns = res.columns.map(lambda col: f'{col[0]}_{col[1]}' if col[0] != 'TeamID' else col[0] )
print(res)

"""
   TeamID  AthleteID_1 Name_1  Score_1  AthleteID_2 Name_2  Score_2
0       1          2.0   Pete      4.6          4.0    Jim      3.6
1       2          1.0    Bob      4.9          3.0  Steve      4.5
2       3          5.0  Frank      4.2          NaN    NaN      NaN
"""

Method 2 :
import pandas as pd

data = {'AthleteID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'TeamID': [2, 1, 2, 1, 3],
        'Name': ['Bob', 'Pete', 'Steve', 'Jim', 'Frank'],
        'Score': [4.9, 4.6, 4.5, 3.6, 4.2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pvt = df.sort_values(by = ['TeamID','Score'],ascending=[True,False]).assign(
Rank = lambda d : d.groupby('TeamID')['Score'].rank(method='first',ascending=False).astype(int)    
)
print(pvt)
'''
   AthleteID  TeamID   Name  Score  Rank
1          2       1   Pete    4.6     1
3          4       1    Jim    3.6     2
0          1       2    Bob    4.9     1
2          3       2  Steve    4.5     2
4          5       3  Frank    4.2     1
'''
pvt1 = pvt.pivot_table(
index = 'TeamID',columns='Rank',aggfunc = 'first'    
).reset_index()
'''
     TeamID AthleteID        Name        Score     
Rank                1    2      1      2     1    2
0         1       2.0  4.0   Pete    Jim   4.6  3.6
1         2       1.0  3.0    Bob  Steve   4.9  4.5
2         3       5.0  NaN  Frank    NaN   4.2  NaN
'''
pvt1.columns = pvt1.columns.map(lambda col : f'{col[0]}_{col[1]}' if col[0] != 'TeamID' else col[0])

'''
   TeamID  AthleteID_1  AthleteID_2 Name_1 Name_2  Score_1  Score_2
0       1          2.0          4.0   Pete    Jim      4.6      3.6
1       2          1.0          3.0    Bob  Steve      4.9      4.5
2       3          5.0          NaN  Frank    NaN      4.2      NaN
'''

Method 3 :
import pandas as pd

data = {'AthleteID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'TeamID': [2, 1, 2, 1, 3],
        'Name': ['Bob', 'Pete', 'Steve', 'Jim', 'Frank'],
        'Score': [4.9, 4.6, 4.5, 3.6, 4.2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

aa = df.sort_values(by=['TeamID','Score'],ascending =[True,False]).assign(
Rank = lambda d : d.groupby('TeamID')['Score'].rank(method ='first',ascending = False).astype(int)    
)
print(aa)
'''
  AthleteID  TeamID   Name  Score  Rank
1          2       1   Pete    4.6     1
3          4       1    Jim    3.6     2
0          1       2    Bob    4.9     1
2          3       2  Steve    4.5     2
4          5       3  Frank    4.2     1
'''
bb = aa.set_index(['TeamID','Rank']).unstack('Rank')
'''
       AthleteID        Name        Score     
Rank           1    2      1      2     1    2
TeamID                                        
1            2.0  4.0   Pete    Jim   4.6  3.6
2            1.0  3.0    Bob  Steve   4.9  4.5
3            5.0  NaN  Frank    NaN   4.2  NaN
'''
bb.columns = bb.columns.map(lambda col : f'{col[0]}_{col[1]}')
bb = bb.reset_index()
'''
   TeamID  AthleteID_1  AthleteID_2 Name_1 Name_2  Score_1  Score_2
0       1          2.0          4.0   Pete    Jim      4.6      3.6
1       2          1.0          3.0    Bob  Steve      4.9      4.5
2       3          5.0          NaN  Frank    NaN      4.2      NaN
'''


Thank you! Unfortunately, I get an error when trying the first method: "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". It is possible for an athlete to appear in multiple teams, in order to participate in different competitions. Could this be what is causing the error? If so, is there a way to make it work? Thanks in advance! The second method crashed my kernel when using pivot_table; I have a large dataset (around 175k rows) but I imagine there is a chance it might return the same error.

please take a look at Method 3 which is Method 1 without cumcount. Apply this. If your Dataset is huge then using pivot_table is not advisable as it performs multiple operations like grouping, aggregation and reshaping, which can lead to performance issues or kernel crashes for very large datasets.@Irina God Bless You.

You can groupby.rank then pivot:
out = (df.assign(rank=df.groupby('TeamID')['Score']
                        .rank('dense', ascending=False).astype(int))
         .pivot(index='TeamID', columns='rank')
         .sort_index(level=1, axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
       )
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
out.reset_index(inplace=True)

Output:
   TeamID  AthleteID_1 Name_1  Score_1  AthleteID_2 Name_2  Score_2
0       1          2.0   Pete      4.6          4.0    Jim      3.6
1       2          1.0    Bob      4.9          3.0  Steve      4.5
2       3          5.0  Frank      4.2          NaN    NaN      NaN

